# How do I fix "No such secret collection at path: /" for gnome-keyring and Arch Linux?

Tags: arch-linux, gnome-keyring

I'm running Arch Linux. When I try to save credentials using Vinagre (VNC client) it gives me an error:

> **Error saving credentials on a locked keyring**
>
> Cannot create item in a locked collection

I found [this guide on the Arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME_Keyring#Using_the_keyring_outside_GNOME), and followed it. In the troubleshooting section it has:

> Ensure that the seahorse package is installed, open it ("Passwords and Keys" in system settings) and select View > By Keyring If there is no keyring in the left column (it will be marked with a lock icon), go to File > New > Password Keyring and give it a name. You will be asked to enter a password. If you do not give the keyring a password it will be unlocked automatically, even when using autologin, but passwords will not be stored securely. Finally, right-click on the keyring you just created and select "Set as default".

When I start up Seahorse it *does* have a **Passwords** section with a `Login` folder with a lock icon to the right of that. Swell, right? Well, nothing really works with that as far as I can tell (no feedback, but apparently I *was* able to delete it)

When I try to create a new keyring it tells me:

> **Couldn't add keyring**
>
> No such secret collection at path: /

I found [this problem](https://askubuntu.com/q/554517/658) with exactly the same message, but `~/.local/share/keyrings` has `drwxr-xr-x` permissions (and has my name *and* group).

So how do I resolve this error so I can store keys in my keyring?

**Edit**:

Some further information - after deleting the useless keyring, Vinagre gives me this message instead:

> No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I could fix it on my machine by sourcing `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d/50-systemd-user.sh` from ~/.xinitrc.
The solution was found on https://bugs.archlinux.org/task/46374 because `journalctl --this-boot --no-pager | grep -i WARNING` showed, that 'org.gnome.keyring.SystemPrompter' failed.

[Reference](https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=212196)

Comment: I'm not complaining too much, since this solved my issue, but surely files in `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc.d` should have been sourced automatically anyway? Perhaps a better solution would be to source `/etc/X11/xinit/xinitrc` instead?

Comment: I don't even have such file in Debian

Answer (score 10):

I had this error in seahorse 3.20.0 on Mint 19 Xfce.  I resolved it by creating the following directory in my home:

```
.local/share/keyrings/
```

Comment: Likewise, on Debian 10 (Buster).

Comment: Had a similar problem on the latest Manjaro after restoring from a backup. Thank you!

Comment: Nothing appeared in seahorse after creating this dir in Debian 11

Answer (score 3):

If you still have the No such interface 'org.freedesktop.Secret.Collection' on object at path /org/freedesktop/secrets/collection/login problem, check out:

https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/GNOME/Keyring

If you use the console login make sure to have both the PAM and the .xinitrc commands. Having them both works for me using i3.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue and before following anything else here, you might want to restart.

Comment: Noting that there's already a specific, accepted answer, why is a restart necessary? A restart of the whole system? Of a component?

Comment: This [SE link](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/32646/how-to-start-the-keyring-daemon-after-a-gnome-shell-crash) notes what you would do to restart the keyring daemon . But if it isn't critical (and this should pretty much just pertain to Desktop use) then you could restart the OS.

Answer (score 0):

While just a workaround rather than a proper fix, but this worked for me: I installed Gnome DE *(the `gnome` package on Archlinux)*, then logged into "Gnome Wayland" session, launched an app that would want to store a password to the keyring *(in my case that was `evolution`)*, and stored the password.

Afterwards the error is gone, `secret-tool` no longer hangs, and keyring started storing passwords in other DEs as well.

Apparently Gnome does some initial configuration that isn't automated when used from other DEs *(e.g. in my case it's KDE with i3)*.