# How can I fix my gnome keyring?

Tags: lxde, gnome-keyring, trisquel

I am using Trisquel version 7 (Belenos), which is based on Ubuntu, with the LXDE desktop environment. It seems to be using the gnome-keyring-daemon to store and remember passwords; however, it doesn't seem to be working properly. For example, when I open Evolution mail, I am prompted for my e-mail/calendar/address book passwords, and then I am asked to give a password for a 'default keyring' to store them. However, the 'default keyring' doesn't seem to persist - I get asked the same questions again and again every time I start Evolution.

I read the man page for gnome-keyring-daemon, but it didn't to help a great deal in explaining how it works. Does anyone know what the problem might be?

**Edit:**

Just to add, I tried removing and then re-installing the gnome keyring package and the problem was still there. I will try doing a 'complete removal' and see if that helps, in case there are some broken config files hanging around.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dug into this a bit more and the issue seems to be similar to the one in this question:

[How do I fix "No such secret collection at path: /" for gnome-keyring and Arch Linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/265503/how-do-i-fix-no-such-secret-collection-at-path-for-gnome-keyring-and-arch-l)

When I loaded up Seahorse and tried to create a new keyring, I got the exact same 'no such secret collection at path ..' error message. It seems the keyring info is supposed to be stored in the folder `~/.local/share/keyrings`; however, in my case, this was actually a file instead of a folder, and just full of some useless junk. So, I renamed the file; created the keyrings folder with the correct permissions; and it seems to be working fine now.